# How can I perform git push within a process?

Tags: java, git, scala, process, subprocess

My goal is to perform git push programatically rather then from a console window.

To this aim I create a process like:

```
val processbuilder=new ProcessBuilder(List("git.exe","push","origin","master").asJava)
process=processbuilder.start()
```

Now, the problem is that git.exe seems to start an other process, to the output/error and input of which I have no access. I know this because if I run it without internet connection, it just prints a message on the error output and quits, as it should. However if I do the same with having an internet connection, it prints nothing on its standard output/error. Also I cannot destroy the process in that case ( see : http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4770092 ), which is an indication that authentication takes place in a separate process that is created by git.exe and to which I have no access.

I tried to get around this by starting cmd.exe as a process and issue git push as a command, but also in this case writing the password to cmd.exe's standard input has no effect.

The platform I'm using is Windows 10 + Scala sbt.

What is the way out of this?

**Edit**:

I'm trying to do this from a JavaFX based Scala application rather than from a console Scala program.

**Edit2**:

Using the sys api here does not solve the problem. If you try to perform the gith push through sys api call, then two things can happen:

If there is no internet connection, it will print an error message on the gui application's console window ( it has one, if you run it with sbt run ).

It there is an internet connection then it will print nothing and you cannot perform the authentication. The process simply detaches and becomes unreachable for you.

The point is that git.exe seems to start a subprocess and you have no access to this subprocess. This is problem is special to Windows to which I gave a link in the question. When you run git in the Windows console window then it takes care of the sub processes input and output for you. You are however not in the same position as the operation system to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a poor man's solution. It will run in a system console window but at least it can be started from the gui app.

The mixture that finally works is this:

1) Create a Windows batch file ( call it "temp.bat" ) which contains the command:

```
git push origin master
```

2) Start cmd.exe as a process and to its standard input write the following line:

```
start temp.bat
```

This will open a console window and initiate the git push. The authentication will be handled properly, you are prompted for the password and can type it in the console window.

Other versions don't work. For example 'start git.exe' won't open a new console window.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scala sys.process API.

```
import sys.process._

val statusCode = "git push origin master" !  // one ! for the statusCode
```

Or:

```
val commandOutput "git push origin master" !! // two ! for getting the output
```

Comment: Unfortunately there was a similar answer that was deleted. I commented on that answer in length. I won't risk losing a long comment again, so I comment on your answer in the question.